# Self-powered heat exchanger w/energy profit?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

It is possible, 
considering the *laws of physics*, to build a heat exchanger that runs on the power it gathers from the environment? A typical heat exchanger uses less power to harvest heat for a household, than it would require if one used an oven, thus creating energy profit.

Let's say that such a device compresses air untill the oxygen and nitrogen condenses, releasing its internal energy (heat) to a fluid, which turns into steam. This steam powers the compressor (for instance).

A design (cross section) I came up with last year, inspired by a jet engine using an axial compressor. It's in Norwegian, but I think you'll get to the point. Airflow "luft" follow arrows from left to right, ends up very cold to the most right part of the drawing. Steam engine lies inside the cylinder.
[image: a busy cat]

Delightful for mathematical evidence for/against the idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible. Every such heat engine would need two temperature baths and you only have one. Having said that, even impossible heat engines, aka perpetual motion machines belong into engineering.

Comment: from where comes the energy ? do you have 2 heat sources at different temperatures ?

Comment: I thought of the internal energy (aka heat or temperature) of the air, not a temperature difference. Only absolute K (kelvin)

Comment: Compression makes temperature rise and creates a second heat source.

Comment: @CuriousOne There are two temperatures in the diagram.